# Understanding lists in list in recursive function - haskell

Tags: haskell

I am writing a function to order a given list by tuples or triples. It should order it by numbers that are between two elements of the list.

for example if given list is `[1,2,3,6,7]` it should return `[[1,2,3], [6,7]]`
because there is zero numbers between **1,2** and **2,3** and also between **6,7**

**here is my code**:

```
import Data.List 

check :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
check listCopy@(x:xs) = 
    let sorted = sort (listCopy) 
        in if (length sorted > 1) 
              then if ((sorted !! 1 ) - (sorted !! 0)) == 1 || ((sorted !! 1 ) - (sorted !! 0)) == 0 
                      then [[x]  ++ check(xs) !! 0] 
                      else [[x]] ++ check(xs)
              else [[x]]
check [] = [[]]
```

`if ((sorted !! 1 ) - (sorted !! 0)) == 1 || ((sorted !! 1 ) - (sorted !! 0)) == 0` is checking if there is 0 numbers between two elements of the list

If above statement is True then `[[x]  ++ check(xs) !! 0]` will add that element to the list and call the function again and take the 1st element that it returns. Example: `[1,2,3,6,7] -> [[1 ++ check [2,3,6,7]]] -> [[1,2 ++ check[3,6,7]]]` and so on...

However when `if ((sorted !! 1 ) - (sorted !! 0)) == 1 || ((sorted !! 1 ) - (sorted !! 0)) == 0`is False it should `else [[x]] ++ check(xs)` set the element inside a list inside a list and call function again AND make another new list inside of list. Example: `[[1,2 ++ check[3,6,7]]]` -> is 6-3 == 0 or 1(False) return `[[1,2,3]] + check[6,7]` which should result in [[1,2,3], [6,7]]

Calling `check[1,2,3,6,7]` however returns `[[1,2,3]]`. I am getting no error, 
but as I know `[[1,2]] ++ [[3,4]]` should result in `[[1,2], [3,4]]` and thats exactly what I am doing in `else [[x]] ++ check(xs)` and somehow my function ends there. Where did I make mistake or it does something that I am missing?

Comment: At no point does your code compute `[[1,2]] ++ [[3,4]]`. There isn't even a `4` in your input list.

Comment: Try to stay away from `!!`. There are three classes of lists to consider: the empty list `[]`, the singleton list `x:[]` (aka `[x]`), and the general case `(x:y:ys)`. Also, solve the main problem for sorted lists with something like `check' :: [Int] -> [[Int]]`; then `check = check' . sort`. There's no need to (re)sort the list in every recursive call.

Comment: Hint: after recursively grouping `(y:ys)`, `x` either goes in a group by itself or gets added to the beginning of the group containing `y`.

Comment: Dont' use `length, !!, head, tail` unless you really have to -- usually you do not. Instead of checking `if length sorted > 1 then ...` use `case sorted of (x1:x2:rest) -> ... ; _ -> ...` which gives you access to the first and second elements without `!!`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A problem here is that you only append the *first sublist*:

```
then [[x]  ++ check(xs) !! 0]
```

You thus make a recursive call that will return a list of sublists, but you "throw away" all the lists but the first one, and you then concatenate the first one. The remaining sublists, are ignored.

You can fix this with:

```
then [[x]  ++ check(xs) !! 0] ++ safeTail check
```

where we implement `safeTail` as:

```
safeTail :: [a] -> [a]
safeTail (x:xs) = xs
safeTail [] = []
```

or, like [@melpomene says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53107986/understanding-lists-in-list-in-recursive-function-haskell/53108305?noredirect=1#comment93111933_53108305):

```
safeTail :: [a] -> [a]
safeTail = drop 1
```

Later it will turn out we can just use `tail`, but with the above code, that is difficult to see.

but the implementation is not very "Haskellish". Your code uses a lot of `(!!)`s, and `length`s. Since `(!!)` runs in *O(k)* with *k* the index to of which we want to obtain the element, and `length` runs in *O(n)* with *n* the length of the list, this will also be quite inefficient.

It makes sense to first sort the list before processing it further. Next we only have to look for the current element `x`, and the next element `n`, and the rest of the elements `xs`, so:

```
go :: (Ord n, Num n) => [n] -> [[n]]
go (x:n:xs) = ...
go other = other
```

In case `n <= x+1`, then we know that the difference between the two numbers is either zero or one, so in that case the *head* (first element) of the recursive call to check should be prepended with `x`, so we can write this like:

```
go :: (Ord n, Num n) => [n] -> [[n]]
go (x:n:xs) | n <= x+1 = (x:r) : rs
            | otherwise = ...
   where (r:rs) = go (n:xs)
go [x] = [[x]]
go [] = []
```

otherwise we can just construct a singleton list, followed by the rest of the list:

```
go :: (Ord n, Num n) => [n] -> [[n]]
go (x:n:xs) | n <= x+1 = (x:r) : rs
            | otherwise = [x]:(r:rs)
    where (r:rs) = go (n:xs)
go [x] = [[x]]
go [] = []
```

we know that `go (n:xs)` has at least one element, since we call the list recursively with one element, and in all cases where the list is non-empty, we return a non-empty list.

By using an *as-pattern*, we can make this a bit more elegant:

```
go :: (Ord n, Num n) => [n] -> [[n]]
go (x:na@(n:xs)) | n <= x+1 = (x:r) : rs
                 | otherwise = [x]: ra
    where ra@(~(r:rs)) = go na
go [x] = [[x]]
go [] = []
```

We can generalize the above, like [@chepner says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53107986/understanding-lists-in-list-in-recursive-function-haskell/53108305?noredirect=1#comment93112235_53108305), to require only the `Eq a`, and `Ord a`:

```
go :: (Ord n, Enum n) => [n] -> [[n]]
go (x:na@(n:xs)) | succ x >= n = (x:r) : rs
                 | otherwise = [x]: ra
    where ra@(~(r:rs)) = go na
go [x] = [[x]]
go [] = []
```

So now we only need to express `check` in terms of `go`, with:

```
import Data.List(sort)

check :: (Ord n, Enum n) => [n] -> [[n]]
check = go . sort
    where go (x:na@(n:xs)) | succ x >= n = (x:r) : rs
                           | otherwise = [x]: ra
              where ra@(~(r:rs)) = go na
          go [x] = [[x]]
          go [] = []
```

or we can let the `check` function operate on `(Eq n, Enum n)` types:

```
import Data.List(sortBy)
import Data.Ord(comparing)

check :: (Ord n, Enum n) => [n] -> [[n]]
check = go . sortBy (comparing fromEnum)
    where go (x:na@(n:xs)) | succ x == n || x == n = (x:r) : rs
                           | otherwise = [x]: ra
              where ra@(~(r:rs)) = go na
          go [x] = [[x]]
          go [] = []
```

Comment: `safeTail = drop 1`

Comment: Generalize to `(Eq a, Enum a) => [a] -> [[a]]`, and all you have to check is that `n == succ x`.

Comment: @chepner: well it is a bit a pity that the `sort` step is nexessary for the "outer" `check` function :(

Comment: You could use `map toEnum . sort . map fromEnum` to sidestep the ordering requirement :)

Comment: (or ``sortBy (compare `on` fromEnum)``; not sure if that would be any more efficient)

Comment: @chepner: well there is a functional difference I guess, since `fromEnum` for `Double` will truncate the result, so information can get "lost" with the `fromEnum` function.

Comment: Ugh, `Double` has an `Enum` instance? *looks at it*. I'm going to go out on a limb and say that no one should rely on that for anything.

Comment: @chepner: well personally I find it a bit problematic, especially since the `succ x` for a double is not the next representable `Double`, but just incremented with `1`., and the saddest thing is that `fromEnum` truncates, so that means that `toEnum . fromEnum` is not the identity function, and that there are `Double`s between `x` and `succ x` :(

Comment: Yeah, that was the point I meant to make. It would be theoretically possible to define a real enumeration of any floating-point type (although in practice I think it would be infeasible, given that the difference between adjacent values isn't fixed). Probably best to just ignore `Enum Double` and the like, and if you choose to take advantage of it, *caveat emptor*.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem I am really sorry to bother, but I am really just getting started with haskell. I don't quite understand the syntax of: go :: (Ord n, Num n) => [n] -> [[n]]. I would Like to add an argument "y" (something like: go :: (Ord n, Num n) => [n] -> Int -> [[n]] ) and use it to find bigger whole between numbers, for example for y = 2 and [1,2,5,6,9] --> [[2,5],[6,9]]? Also I noticed that It prints also the numbers that are alone (Example go [1,2,5,7,8,20] --> [[1,2], ---> [5] <---,[7,8]]). Would it be possible to eliminate those numbers? I am really struggling with haskell syntax

Comment: @cheshire: I think you then better start with some list functions that are simpler, like `map` and `filter`, etc. See here for some details about the list data structure: http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#an-intro-to-lists

Answer (score 2):

Well this is an interesting question and here is an experimental approach in applicative style. Yes it looks a little convoluted but in fact very simple. The only thing that i don't like is the usage of `last` function. May be we can find a way to drop that somehow.

```
splitConsequtives :: Integral a => [a] -> [[a]]
splitConsequtives xs = foldr id [[last xs]] $ zipWith f <*> tail $ xs
                       where f x y | y-x == 1  = (:) <$> (x:) . head <*> tail
                                   | otherwise = ([x]:)

*Main> splitConsequtives [1,2,3,6,7]
[[1,2,3],[6,7]]
*Main> splitConsequtives [-1,2,3,6,8,9]
[[-1],[2,3],[6],[8,9]]
```

The idea is to place the constructor functions in a list those will eventually construct our whole result list when chained up by folding. List constructor `(:)` is right associative and that's why i use `foldr`.

It all starts with `zipWith`ing our `xs` list with it's `tail` by the `f` function like `zipWith f xs (tail xs)`. The `f :: a -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]` function is where we get our applicatives  as elements of the resulting list.

OK..! Now lets focus at the `f` function which takes `x` and `y` as parameters.

- If `y` is subsequent of `x` then our `[[a]] -> [[a]]` type function
  is `(:) <$> (x:) . head <*> tail` which takes a list of lists of
  numbers then takes the sublist at the `head`, appends `x` to it and
  puts everything back together. So if our result being constructed
  (the accumulator parameter of `foldr`) is `[[7], [9,10]]` and `x` is
  `6` then we shall get `[[6,7],[9,10]]`.
- If `y` is not a subsequent of `x` then our `[[a]] -> [[a]]` type
  function is `([x]:)`. So if our result being constructed (the
  accumulator parameter of `foldr`) is `[[6,7], [9,10]]` and `x` is `3`
  then we shall get `[[3],[6,7],[9,10]]`.

One interesting point to notice is the type of iterating function that we use for `foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`. You expect it to be of type `a -> b -> b` but `id :: a -> a` looks different. How is this possible..? I believe it is because `a ~ [[a]] -> [[a]]` and `b ~ [[a]]` in `(a -> b -> b)` of `foldr`.

Comment: for me, `splitConsequtives [] = [] ;
splitConsequtives xs =  foldr ($) [[last xs]] $ zipWith f xs $ tail xs
 where 
 f x y ~(g:gs) | x+1 == y  =  (x : g) : gs
 | otherwise =  [x] : g : gs` is more readable and clear. :)

Comment: @WillNess Respect..! While honestly, i think, people coding in Haskell should know applicatives by heart as a reflex in their mind set so that my code should be straightforward to read. I believe only then one may get comfortable with the tricks like continuation passing (like we did in our recent answers). I also don't like  the list comprehensions and the **do** notation but that's another thing for another time :)

Comment: I actually do like LCs and `do` very much. even MCs, MonadComprehensions. matters of taste...

Comment: (I used to hate `do` before I learned to love it. :) but I like my `do`s with explicit separators -- braces and semicolons all the way. the "naked" `do` code I do dislike. maybe that's the old lisper in me, but have your code break because of one accidental space? what is that? )